# "autocomplete=off" Html attribute not working in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, navigator

hello the autocomplete=off doesn't work in chrome
To disable autocompletion in forms, you can set the autocomplete attribute to "off": but 
i tried "nope" / "fake" / "random" but not working it work only to captcha input

Comment: @GovindParashar you're question as been closed for duplicated (for mine)

Comment: but they response not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="password" name="whatever" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

This will get you close to what you are trying to do, but Chrome seemingly is trying to make it as hard as possible to control the behavior in your site. So there are quite a few ways to have this not act as intended.

Comment: doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Alright, I'll see if I can find other solutions.

Comment: it only work for a date input and captcha, i can't understand whay. and i don't have a passowrd input in my form

Comment: i added a hidden <input> with autocomplete="on" as a first children element of the form. <input autocomplete="on" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;"> so that's working now :D

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out @chaima

Comment: tnx so much @the_legitTDM